# make a children not scroll inside listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I made a `Column` widget which contains some `Row` inside it, and in the end I got a `ListView` widget, and It showing me some pixels error, So I changed the `Column` to `ListView` and the pixels error gone, But I need the first child inside the `ListView` to be in fixed position. Please help. the code below is sample.

```
SafeArea(
   child: ListView(
     children: [
       Row(),
       Row(),
       Row(),
       Row(),
       Row(),
       Row(),
     ]
   )
 )
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits.

Comment: am not new here. my account got reset automatically. No idea why! anyway thanks for welcoming,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of what you can do, enter the ListView inside a Column and put a the widget you want to fixed above it, then wrap the ListView in Expanded to prevent the overflow:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Title'),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('Hello')
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```